# HTML Purifier : using basic example without success

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am trying to use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) without success.

My code is below :

```
    <?php
include_once('purifier/htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML', 'Doctype', 'HTML5');

$filter = new HTMLPurifier($config);
include 'config.php';


$name =  $filter->purify($con, $_POST["name"]);
```

I am using this correctly. In addition I am using HTML5. When reading the docs I do not see it being an option. Is my config.php a problem ?

I looked at the basic example and thought it would be straight forward. My path is correct as I checked it with:

```
$filename = 'purifier/htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

I get an error with "cannot open stream".

```
Notice: Using deprecated API: use $config->set('Core.Encoding', ...) 

instead in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 901

Notice: Using deprecated API: use $config->set('HTML.Doctype', ...) instead in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 901

Warning: Value not supported, valid values are: HTML 4.01 Transitional, HTML 4.01 Strict, XHTML 1.0 Transitional, XHTML 1.0 Strict, XHTML 1.1 in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 901

Warning: parse_ini_file( <script>alert("hello");</script>): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 836

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 684

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier
```

Errors Added

I ve tried the following code change as the and cleared some errors

```
<?php
require 'purifier/htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

include 'config.php';

$hs = $purifier->purify($con,$_POST["hs"]);
```

I still get following errors and the one I refer to at the beginning.

```
    Warning: parse_ini_file( ddddddddddffffffffffffff): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 836

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 684

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\tests\purifier\htmlpurifier-4.7.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Lexer.php on line 298
```

I want to use it on multiple post values.

Comment: Is "cannot open stream" the real and complete error message ?

Comment: @Michel errors added

Comment: Hi, Fintan! `$purifier->purify($con,$_POST["hs"]);` - what is `$con` in this code snippet? The `purify()` method in the example on the HTML Purifier website ( http://htmlpurifier.org/docs ) takes one argument - your dirty HTML. To me that appears like it ought to translate to `$purifier->purify($_POST["hs"]);` in your code.